# Primitive function in R

Tags: r, primitive, scoping, lexical-scope

Can someone give me explanation for the below sentence highlighted in Bold.

"Primitive functions are only found in the base package, and since they operate at a low level, they can be more efficient (primitive replacement functions don’t have to make copies), and can have different rules for argument matching (e.g., switch and call). **This, however, comes at a cost of behaving differently from all other functions in R. Hence the R core team generally avoids creating them unless there is no other option.**

Source Link:http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping

Comment: See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive) on why `.Internal` is preferred over `.Primitive`. And, also, as simple example of "closure"s VS "builtin"s, in argument matching, see `.subset` which is defined as `function (x, ...)  .Primitive(".subset")`: with `x = letters[1:3]; wrapsubset = function(x, ...) .subset(x, ...)` see (1) `.subset(notAnArgument = x, anIndex = 1L)` VS `wrapsubset(notAnArgument = x, anIndex = 1L)` and (2) `.subset(1L, x = x)` VS `wrapsubset(1L, x = x)`

Comment: It may be helpful if you provide more guidance on what you're looking for. What would you like more information on? The R Core Team? The definition of primitive functions in R, or how they behave?

Comment: how to view source code for `.Prmiitive` functions like for example `base::prod()` would be helpful if an answer would be provided here in the future.